# Change cell value based on another cell value

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

i have one item with purchase and sale rate (Apple : $10 : $12 ). I have two cells A1 and D1. I want to do, if "purchase" in D1 then A1=$10 likewise "sale" in D1 then A1=$12 against item name (Apple).

Answer (score 0):

In cell A1: =If(D1="purchase",10,If(D1="sale",12,"Error"))

This will put the proper amount in cell A1 and display Error if an invalid value is in D1.

Comment: Thanks for your help sir but I was looking for little bit different. I figure out it myself like this.

Comment: =If(D1="purchase",Vlookup(B1,F1:H1,2,False),=If(D1="sale",Vlookup(B1,F1:H1,3,False))     B1=criteria (Apple) and F1:H1=range (Apple, $10, $12)